# Cannot open device (e.g. png) for plotting in RMarkdown, but not R script

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

A minimal example:

The following R script gives the correct output:

```
png("test.png")
dev.cur() #quartz_off_screen 2
plot(1:10)
dev.off() #null device 1, file "test.png" generated in getwd()
```

However, when I wrap these codes in an R markdown chunk, and if I send them *line-by-line* to the console, I get the following result:

````
```{r}
png("test.png")
dev.cur() #null device 1
plot(1:10)#plot appears inline in the editor's pane
dev.off() #Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
# file "test.png" not generated
```
````

The same code runs fine and generates the expected file if it was run not *line-by-line* but altogether using the *run current chunk* function.

It seems as if Rstudio internally calls "dev.new()" when encountering any plot functions, so that it can direct all plotting output to the editor's pane.

I wonder if this is by design in Rstudio and whether other users have found this behavior non-intuitive -- it took me quite some time to find out the source of the problem for not being able to open a png device and output the plots like I'm used to doing.

Comment: most of the time, ggplot graphs + ggsave are a better solution than using png and dev in rmarkdown.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it works for me.
Are you sure all your plot windows are closed before to run knit?

Comment: Yes. I can reproduce the error on my Macbook Pro (R version 3.3.2, OS X Yosemite 10.10.5).  What I did was to open start a fresh R session, create a new R markdown file, and put in the script as shown above, then send them line-by-line to the console. Note that if I run the whole chunk, the problem is *not* encountered.

Comment: Ok, that's because you are using the notebook version.

Comment: I see. I thought the notebook function is controlled by the YAML header line -- output: html_notebook. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the notebook version.

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html#overview

you can disable notebook mode by clicking the gear in the editor toolbar and choosing Chunk Output in Console.